# Is Tomcat redeploying my web app over and over?

Tags: java, tomcat

My Java web application began experiencing sporadic outages. Peering into the logs, I see this pattern repeated **hundreds** of times throughout the day.

```
INFO: Undeploying context [/TheChosenOne]
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/TheChosenOne.war
INFO: Deployment of web application archive /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/TheChosenOne.war has finished in 323 ms
```

As far as I know, no human is (purposefully) responsible for this. What would cause this to happen? What triggers a redeployment like this without someone explicitly asking for it? Is this strictly a Tomcat configuration issue? Or can the code itself cause this to happen?

Comment: *"no human is (purposefully) responsible for this"* then they do that unintentionally by using a build pipeline which triggers a re-deployment?

Comment: I'm investigating such aspects. Even if it were part of a build pipeline, we're not pushing new versions down said pipeline. So, these redeployments seem to happen all on their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tomcat can be configured to check on a regular basis if the files of
>   your application have changed on disk, and redeploy the application if
>   they did. As checking if files have changed is incredibly cpu and
>   memory intensive it is recommend to disable the automatic web
>   application redeployment feature, on production servers which is
>   enabled by default.

Modify it so that it resembles the snippet below:

```
<host appbase="webapps" autodeploy="false" name="localhost" unpackwars="true" xmlnamespaceaware="false" xmlvalidation="false" />
```

For more information on autodeploy, see http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html#Common_Attributes

Comment: Checking my config, `autodeploy` was indeed set to `true`. I'll set that to `false` and see if things improve.

Comment: A couple hours later... I haven't seen a single redeploy in the logs. Unless something changes, I'm gonna have to declare this answer the winner. :)

Comment: I wish I knew the true root cause. Even with this option on, I don't know why Tomcat was seeing a "new web app" to deploy every few seconds. Regardless, we don't need it enabled. We do manual deployments anyway.